# How to check if an condition is true in protractor?

Tags: if-statement, protractor, conditional-statements

I want to show message based on the following condition. But it's not working. Can anyone help me in this regard.

```
if(errorMsg.isDisplayed()==='false'){
      console.log('valid');
}else{
      console.log('invalid');
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Here is the code:

```
errorMsg.isPresent().then(function(result) {
      if (result) {
         console.log('Invalid');

      }  else {
         console.log('Valid');
      }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to check that the `errorMsg.isDisplayed` method is false. You can simply do

```
if(errorMsg.isDisplayed()){
  console.log('valid');
 }else{
  console.log('invalid');
};
```

This is provided that the `isDisplayed()` method works for the element that you have in question.

Comment: Thank you..Its working..but i am getting the console log at the starting but not following the code sequence.can you help with that?

Comment: Because `console.log` is an asynchronous method, it doesn't follow a specific order/

Comment: What i need to do if i want to get it in  specific order?